# Wait for result from Coroutine and then use it in Composable function

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines

I am creating a video scraper, and it has the following function which scrapes the video source from a URL that has been given as the parameter:

```
fun scrapeVideoSrcFromUrl(url: String): String? {
    val document = Jsoup.connect(url).get()

    for (element in document.getElementsByTag("script")) {
        if (element.attr("type") == "application/ld+json") {
            val content = element.data()
            val array = JsonParser.parseString(content).asJsonArray

            val embedUrl = Gson().fromJson(array.get(0).asJsonObject.get("embedUrl"), String::class.java)
            var embedId = ""

            for (char in embedUrl.dropLast(1).reversed()) {
                if (char != '/') {
                    embedId += char
                } else {
                    break
                }
            }

            val doc = Jsoup.connect("$RUMBLE_API_URL${embedId.reversed()}").ignoreContentType(true).get()
            val jsonData = doc.getElementsByTag("body").first()?.text()

            val mp4 = JsonParser.parseString(jsonData).asJsonObject.get("u").asJsonObject.get("mp4").asJsonObject.get("url").toString()

            return mp4.replace("\"", "")
        }
    }

    return null
}
```

I want to show this in a dialog for a certain link using `ExoPlayer`, so I did the following:

```
@Composable
fun VideoPlayer(videoSrc: String) {
    val context = LocalContext.current

    val exoPlayer = remember {
        ExoPlayer.Builder(context).build().apply {
            setMediaItem(
                MediaItem.fromUri(
                    videoSrc
                )
            )
            prepare()
            playWhenReady = true
        }
    }

    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        DisposableEffect(key1 = Unit) {
            onDispose {
                exoPlayer.release()
            }
        }

        AndroidView(
            factory = {
                StyledPlayerView(context).apply {
                    player = exoPlayer
                    layoutParams =
                        FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
                        )
                }
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Then, in the main Composable:

```
if (openDialog) {
        AlertDialog(
            onDismissRequest = {
                openDialog = false
            },
            title = {
                Column {
                    Text(
                        text = viewModel.currentRumbleSearchResult?.title ?: ""
                    )
                    Spacer(
                        Modifier.height(8.dp)
                    )
                    Text(
                        text = "By ${viewModel.currentRumbleSearchResult?.channel?.name ?: ""}",
                        style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleSmall
                    )
                }
            },
            text = {
                        VideoPlayer(RumbleScraper.create().scrapeVideoSrcFromUrl("https://rumble.com/v1m9oki-our-first-automatic-afk-farms-locals-minecraft-server-smp-ep3-live-stream.html")!!)
            
            },
            confirmButton = {
                TextButton(
                    onClick = {
                        openDialog = false
                    }
                ) {
                    Text("Exit")
                }
            }
        )
    }
```

After running that code I keep getting `NetworkOnMainThread` exceptions, and I tried many things to fix it but nothing worked.

So I am unsure what to do as to how I can go around fixing this. I was wondering how I would go around waiting in the background for a result and then show it in the Compose function when it returns the value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
var videoSrc by remember { mutableStateOf<String?>(null) }

LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        videoSrc = RumbleScraper.create().scrapeVideoSrcFromUrl("")
    }
}

text = { VideoPlayer(videoSrc) }
```

You can also call the `scrapeVideoSrcFromUrl` inside your viewModel and update some state that you will use in UI.

---

If you want to run it in response to some event like item click, you will be better of with something like this:

```
val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

Button(
    onClick = {
        scope.launch {
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { ... }
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: How do I run the `LaunchedEffect` when a user presses an item?

Comment: @thebluepandabear you can use `rememberCoroutineScope`